# how install shapely on windows so it can be imported from matlab?

Tags: matlab, manifest, ctypes, shapely, geos

i'm on windows 7/64.  shapely doesn't offer windows installers on their [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely), even though they [seem to](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/109) [have recently](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/104).  their pypi page, and their [README](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) say to use [chris gohlke's unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely).  i'm not clear on the reason -- something like pypi can't install dll's, so you have to make an installer by hand if your code depends on a dll, but making the installer is a pain because you need ms visual studio or something?

anyway, gohlke's binary works fine for me in winpython (2.7), but not when i try to import using matlab's new [python bridge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html).  shapely is the only python library on windows that is giving me this trouble in matlab -- i can use openCV, numpy, scipy, scikit's, mosek, picos, PIL, future, all fine.  it's also the only library for which i need gohlke's installer.  so i think there is a connection.

when i `py.importlib.import_module('shapely')` in matlab, i get this:

```
PyException with properties:

ExceptionObject: [1x3 py.tuple]
     identifier: 'MATLAB:Python:PyException'
        message: 'Python Error: [Error 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed'
          cause: {}
          stack: [1x1 struct]
```

a popup also comes up:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
R6034 "an application has made an attempt to load the c runtime library incorrectly"
```

googling this, i get
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235560(v=vs.90).aspx

> Visual Studio 2008. An application has made an attempt to load the C
>   runtime library without using a manifest. This is an unsupported way
>   to load Visual C++ DLLs. You need to modify your application to build
>   with a manifest. 
>   Applications must use a manifest to load the C runtime library. For
>   more information, see Visual C++ Libraries as Shared Side-by-Side
>   Assemblies and Manifest Generation in Visual Studio. ... To correct
>   this error Rebuild your application to include a manifest. Building an
>   application with Visual Studio automatically puts the manifest into
>   the resulting .exe or .dll file. If you are building at the command
>   line, use the mt.exe tool to add the manifest as a resource. Use
>   resource ID 1 if you build an .exe, and resource ID 2 if you build a
>   .dll. For more information, see How to: Embed a Manifest Inside a
>   C/C++ Application."

this seems to relate to chris gohlke's [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108273/cartopy-in-iis-isapi-wsgi-application-fails-to-import-geos-c-dll#comment35357436_23108273).

here are some more things i've tried.

in matlab:

```
>> x=py.ctypes.util.find_library('geos_c')

x =

  Python NoneType with no properties.

    None
```

but same in python!

```
>>> from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> print find_library('geos_c')
None
```

however, i can use shapely from python:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon, Point
>>> Point()
<shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x000000000399F2E8>
```

in matlab:

```
>> x=py.ctypes.CDLL('C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll')

x =

  Python CDLL with no properties.

    <CDLL 'C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll',
handle e3f60000 at 7078b588>

>> x.GEOSversion()
No appropriate method, property, or field 'GEOSversion' for class
'py.ctypes.CDLL'.

>> x.initGEOS()
No appropriate method, property, or field 'initGEOS' for class 'py.ctypes.CDLL'.

>> x=py.ctypes.CDLL('C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll').GEOSversion()
No appropriate method, property, or field 'GEOSversion' for class
'py.ctypes.CDLL'.

Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

>> x=py.ctypes.CDLL('C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\site-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll').initGEOS()
No appropriate method, property, or field 'initGEOS' for class 'py.ctypes.CDLL'.

Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

>> py.dir(x)

ans =

  Python list with no properties.

    ['_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__',
'__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__',
'__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
'__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_flags_', '_func_restype_',
'_handle', '_name']
```

in python:

```
>>> from ctypes import CDLL
>>> x=CDLL("C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.am
d64\\Lib\\site-packages\\shapely\\DLLs\\geos_c.dll")
>>> print x
<CDLL 'C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\Lib\si
te-packages\shapely\DLLs\geos_c.dll', handle e3f60000 at 2292cc0>
>>> x.GEOSversion()
-469489536
>>> x.initGEOS()
36606784
>>> dir(x)
['GEOSversion', '_FuncPtr', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '
__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__hash__', '__in
it__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__se
tattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_func_fla
gs_', '_func_restype_', '_handle', '_name', 'initGEOS']
```

a search for `geos_c.dll` just shows `shapely`'s directory in my python's `site-packages`.

a [couple other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14680947/1441998) [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273594/run-time-error-r6034-when-compiling-from-the-command-prompt#comment43021210_27273594) suggest it's matlab putting its incompatible copy of msvcr*.dll somewhere on the path, and suspiciously:

```
>> py.pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint(py.sys.path)
['',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015a\\bin\\win64',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

so:

```
>> import py.sys.path
>> path.remove('C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\win64')
>> py.pprint.PrettyPrinter().pprint(py.sys.path)
['',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\FontTools',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nlab\\Downloads\\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\\python-2.7.9.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
>> py.importlib.import_module('shapely')

ans = 

  Python module with properties:

                 ftools: [1x1 py.module]
    ctypes_declarations: [1x1 py.module]

    <module 'shapely' from 'C:\Users\nlab\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.5\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\shapely\__init__.pyc'>
```

yay!  but as soon as i try to use it, i get exactly the same R6034 error popup

```
>> py.shapely.geometry.Point()
```

triggers the error popup > 10 times!

the following just does it once:

```
>> py.importlib.import_module('shapely.geometry')
Python Error: [Error 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

i also removed `...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages` from `sys.path` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

we want to use matlab's msvcr, not hide it.  in shapely, replacing
`CDLL(find_library('c'))` with `CDLL('C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015a\\bin\\win64\\msvcr100.dll')` makes it all work.  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389227/how-do-i-load-a-c-dll-from-the-sxs-in-python) seems to be a method that would determine that path automatically, appropriate for wherever you are invoking shapely from.